# .htaccess rewrite URLs when routing with PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to figure out how to rewrite a url. I'm using a PHP router which redirects all traffic to index.php.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Router

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example.com/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

For the username profiles, the router provides the profile page like this:

```
Router::get('/u=(:all)', function() {
     include 'content/profile.php';
});
```

How can rewrite the url from:

```
example.com/u=exampleUser
```

to

```
example.com/exampleUser
```

I can't seem to find a solution. I'm guessing all I would need is to remove the "u=" part of the url.

Comment: If you were to use `example.com/exampleUser`, then _how_ should your routing mechanism know that this is supposed to be a user profile, and not something else?

Comment: could I route it through the router instead? or would that be inefficient? i.e I could update a file from the DB when users register that includes a new route to profile.php for each name.

Comment: You should rather use routes like `/user/username` or `/profile/username` or something like that – that way, it is clear to your router, that those are meant to be user profiles, and that `/foo/…` is something else.